# How to make bottomNavigationView badge to cover the item icon without using any custom view or library?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have a badge on `BottomNavigationView` item but it is getting displayed outside the item icon. I want it to overlap the item icon on the top right corner.

Comment: Just use this:
   `yourBottomNav.showBadge(R.id.bottomNavigationClockMenuId).apply { 
            number = 1  
        }` You can also remove it if you want.

Comment: Yes it does show a badge, but i need to know a way to update its position within the menu item if possible. Currently i can set its gravity to the corners of menu item only.

Comment: Well, I have left an answer (solution) regarding your problem. Check if it works or not. If works, make it as the correct answer. Thanks @Neelabh

Answer (score 0):

Visit These Url

https://youtu.be/UyHd75_tUiI

show project

https://github.com/axarlotwala/CafeDelear

These Code Work For Bottom Notification badge

```
BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = 
              (BottomNavigationMenuView) navigation.getChildAt(0);
        View view = menuView.getChildAt(1);
        BottomNavigationItemView itemView = 
                                 (BottomNavigationItemView) view;
        View badge = 
           LayoutInflater
               .from(this)
               .inflate(R.layout.notification_badge,itemView,true);
        tvCount = badge.findViewById(R.id.tvCount);
        tvCount.setText("0");
```

Comment: Yes, currently i am using this approach and it works just fine. But instead of inflating a new layout and setting its position, i want to adjust the position of default badge provided by the bottomNavigationView.

Answer (score 0):

So here is your solution:

**This is** to create or set a badge to your navigation item :

```
      // 'nav_view' the id of your BottomNavigationView    
      nav_view.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.navigation_history).number = 10
```

**And this is** to set your badge gravity:

```
      nav_view.getOrCreateBadge(R.id.navigation_history).badgeGravity = BadgeDrawable.TOP_START 
      // you can also use BadgeDrawable.TOP_UP and BadgeDrawable.BOTTOM_END 
      // as BadgeDrawable.TOP_END is the default gravity.
```

Hope is helps, Let me know.